# Android download directory from FTP error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ftp, audio-player, android-music-player

I have a music player that downloads a directory from the FTP server to the SD card. And the player downloads and accepts server settings (there are two versions of ME and CE), but it happens after downloading the application crashes. When I delete some folders after downloading it works normally in ME mode, but when I download it and it takes the CE mode all the time the application crashes.

```
public class FTPManager {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = FTPManager.class.getName();
    private static final String HOST = "*******";
    private static final String LOGIN = "*******";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "*******";
    private static final int REPEAT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5 * 1000;

    private int mCommandAttempts;

    private String host;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private FTPClient mFtpClient;

    private FTPManager(String host, String login, String password) {
        this.host = host;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
    }

    public FTPManager() {
        this(HOST, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
    }

    public boolean connect() {
        mCommandAttempts = 5;
        return attemptConnect();
    }

    private boolean attemptConnect() {
        try {
            mFtpClient.connect(host);
            mFtpClient.login(this.login, password);
            mFtpClient.setPassive(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(REPEAT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                return false;
            }
            mCommandAttempts--;
            if (mCommandAttempts > 0) {
                return attemptConnect();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public List<String> listFiles() {
        return listFiles(FTPFile.TYPE_FILE);
    }

    public List<String> listDirectores() {
        return listFiles(FTPFile.TYPE_DIRECTORY);
    }

    private List<String> listFiles(int type) {
        mCommandAttempts = 5;
        return attemptListFiles(type);
    }

    private List<String> attemptListFiles(int type) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FTPFile[] files = mFtpClient.list();
            for (FTPFile file : files) {
                if (file.getType() == type) {
                    names.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(REPEAT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                return names;
            }
            mCommandAttempts--;
            if (mCommandAttempts > 0) {
                return attemptListFiles(type);
            }
        }
        return names;
    }

    public boolean downloadFile(OutputStream outputStream, String ftpName) {
        mCommandAttempts = 5;
        return attemptDownloadFile(outputStream, ftpName);
    }


    private boolean attemptDownloadFile(OutputStream outputStream, String ftpName) {
        try {
            mFtpClient.download(ftpName, outputStream, 0, null);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(REPEAT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                return false;
            }
            mCommandAttempts--;
            if (mCommandAttempts > 0) {
                return attemptDownloadFile(outputStream, ftpName);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean changeDirectory(String path) {
        mCommandAttempts = 5;
        return attemptChangeDirectory(path);
    }

    private boolean attemptChangeDirectory(String path) {
        try {
            mFtpClient.changeDirectory(path);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(REPEAT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                return false;
            }
            mCommandAttempts--;
            if (mCommandAttempts > 0) {
                return attemptChangeDirectory(path);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean release() {
        if (mFtpClient != null) try {
            mFtpClient.logout();
            mFtpClient.disconnect(true);
            mFtpClient = null;
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

And

```
public class FTPDirectory implements Parcelable {

    private StringBuilder builder;

    public FTPDirectory(String host) {
        builder = new StringBuilder(host);
    }

    protected FTPDirectory(Parcel in) {
        builder = new StringBuilder(in.readString());
    }

    public static final Creator<FTPDirectory> CREATOR = new Creator<FTPDirectory>() {
        @Override
        public FTPDirectory createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new FTPDirectory(in);
        }

        @Override
        public FTPDirectory[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FTPDirectory[size];
        }
    };

    public FTPDirectory append(String path) {
        builder.append("/").append(path);
        return this;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static FTPDirectory getImgDirectory() {
        return new FTPDirectory("/img");
    }

    public static FTPDirectory getAdDirectory() {
        return new FTPDirectory("/adv");
    }

    public static FTPDirectory getMusicDirectory() {
        return new FTPDirectory("/music");
    }


    public static FTPDirectory getChannelDirectory(String channel, int index) {
        return getChannelRootDirectory(channel)
                .append(Integer.toString(index));
    }

    public static FTPDirectory getChannelRootDirectory(String channel) {
        return getMusicDirectory()
                .append(channel);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FTPDirectory{" +
                "Path=" + builder.toString() +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(getPath());
    }
}
```

I think somewhere here there may be a mistake. It turns out that one file reads and the other does not, but the format is the same. Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have any error in the log ? Are you working in Java ? What is your main class (or how do you call your 2 classes here ...) ?

Comment: Yes Java. No error in  log. The application crashes after downloading in the CE version and from some channel list.